# Can I use Visual Studio 2017 to develop Python Azure Functions?

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I have added the *Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools* Extension to Visual Studio Professional 2017.

I have then created an *Azure Function* project via *File >> New Project >> Visual C# >> Azure Functions*

I could not see a python version of the Azure Functions project.

I the right click on *Solution Explorer >> Project >> Add >> New Item*
and get:

[image]

I can now add a C# based azure function.

However I'd rather develop a python function, and I was wondering if there is a way to manage developing/publishing/source controlling a Python Azure Function from Visual Studio 2017?

I know you can create python/node/f# functions in the Azure portal but how do we do outside of the portal?

Answer (score 2):

At this time, the VS 2017 Functions tooling is only for C# functions, so it cannot be used for Python functions.

You can still develop them locally using the command line [Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local).

As a side point (not directly related to question), please do keep in mind that Python support is marked as experimental, and is unfit for most Production use.

Comment: Thanks David. I have been using the C# function tooling in VS2017 and it's great, so I'll stick with that for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reluctant on creating azure functions via Visual studio, you have to use 2015. 2017 does not support all the languages.

even I was struggling to create a Python based Azure function via VS until I found this link:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/12/01/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/